# Linux and multiple monitors not working properly on docked laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, multiple-monitors, monitor-settings

I'm working on a docked [HP ProBook 650](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-HP-ProBook-650-G1-H5G74E-Notebook.108634.0.html) and two external monitors.
On Windows it works fine, but my work requires me to use Linux (tried both Ubuntu and Debian).

Got two seperate problems:

1. On Ubuntu all three monitors work - but my graphics twitch and break.
2. On Debian only one monitor can be active others are in "disconnected" state

I've searched and tried a lot of things - but since I'm a novice in using Linux operating systems I'm seeking help on how to solve any of those two problems?

Or a suggestion for a better Linux option for a work station would be handy as well?

> **lspci | grep VGA**
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]

---

> **xrandr**
>   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   eDP1 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      1920x1080     60.01 +  59.93    40.00
>      1680x1050     59.95    59.88
>      1600x1024     60.17
>      1400x1050     59.98
>      1280x1024     60.02
>      1440x900      59.89
>      1280x960      60.00
>      1360x768      59.80    59.96
>      1152x864      60.00
>      1024x768      60.00
>      800x600       60.32    56.25
>      640x480       59.94
>   VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputs you display above only report the existence of one monitor, not two. **If** you have given the above commands when you had both external monitors connected to your pc, then most likely there is a driver problem. You will have to investigate this by sifting thru the error messages in `/var/log/Xorg*`.

The reason why I am saying this is that X is, by now, essentially self-configuring, so if anything fails, it is most likely due to the absence of some essential component.

You may at any instant try to allow X to reconfigure itself by means of

```
       sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg
```

Alternatively, you may follow the ever helpful Arch Linux wiki about [MultiHead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#) (which is the configuration you are attempting). But do not be confused, **all** Linux distros use X, and are thus strictly equivalent in coping with your configuration.

Comment: Yeah, appered to be a driver problem. Managed to sort it out. Thank you.